# XsltListViewWebPart cross site view unexpected error

Tags: 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part

We are programmatically adding an XsltListViewWebpart to a SPWeb in SharePoint 2013 Server. The web part is configured to show tasks from a list and view on another spweb. It works fine until it suddenly crashes with "unexpected error".

Correlation ID in log:

> Application error when access /dept/0300/SitePages/Tasks.aspx,
>   Error=Value does not fall within the expected range.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ConvertToServiceRelUrl(String
>   strUrl, String strBaseUrl)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.JSGrid.SPGridInitGenerator.GetInitObject(String
>   qualifier)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.GanttV4.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     ...  at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Anyone have a solution for this?